# Fragment Getting Method from Another Class

Tags: android, class, methods, android-fragments

I have an Android app that uses fragments. I'm also following a tutorial ([CallLogs Tutorial](http://android2011dev.blogspot.ie/2011/08/get-android-phone-call-historylog.html)) to get the calls history.

I have the a class made by the tutorial in the link but now I want to get data from this class and use it in one of my fragments.

I've tried something like the following;

```
    int callsMade = new GetUsage().getCallDetails();
    String callsmade = String.valueOf(callsMade);

    Log.e("Calls Made:", "Texts: " + callsmade);
```

But I keep getting an error on the "Cursor managedCursor" line (NB: I've changed the managedCursor to getContentResolver since managedCursor is deprecated and get the error too)

Is there something I'm doing wrong here? Anthing ye can think of that I can change?

Thanks alot for any help you can provide.

EDIT:
Code for getCallDetails();

```
public int getCallDetails() 
{

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Cursor callsCursor = getContentResolver().query( CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,null, null,null, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC");
    //Cursor planCursor=PlansHelper.query("plans", null, null, null, null);
    int name = callsCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME );
    int number = callsCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.NUMBER ); 
    int type = callsCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.TYPE );
    int date = callsCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int duration = callsCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
    int allduration = 0;


    sb.append( "Call Details :");
    while ( callsCursor.moveToNext() ) 
    {

        String phName = callsCursor.getString( name );
        String phNumber = callsCursor.getString( number );

        String callType = callsCursor.getString( type );
        int callTypeCode = Integer.parseInt(callType);

        String callDate = callsCursor.getString( date );
        Date formatDate = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String dateStr = sdf.format(formatDate);

        String userdate = "18/03/2014";

        //Date parseddate = sdf.parse(userdate1);

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        try {
            c.setTime(sdf.parse(userdate));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, -5);  // number of days to add
        userdate = sdf.format(c.getTime());  // dt is now the new date


        String callDuration = callsCursor.getString(duration);
        float durationToFloat =Float.parseFloat(callDuration);
        float durationToMins = durationToFloat/60;
        int durationRounded = Math.round(durationToMins);
        int callDurationMin = durationRounded;


        if(callTypeCode==CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE)
        {

            //if(dateStr.equals(userdate) || dateStr.equals(userdate1))
            if(formatDate.after(c.getTime()))
            {
                sb.append("\nName:--- " + phName + "\nPhone Number:--- " + phNumber + " \nCall Date:--- " + dateStr
                        + " \nCall duration in min :--- " + callDurationMin);
                sb.append("\n----------------------------------");
                allduration = allduration + callDurationMin;
                Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Done");
            }
        }


    }

    sb.append("##" + allduration + "##");
    getCalls.setText(sb.toString());
    callsCursor.close();

    return allduration;

}
```

Comment: can u pls share code for getCallDetails()

Comment: @Anthony Sorry, I probably should of added that at the start instead of telling ye to look at a tutorial. Just added it now. 

Please Note: I dont actually want all the data from this code; just the duaration of the calls

Comment: have you added permission android.permission.READ_CONTACTS ??

Comment: I did. I can run the activity itself no problem but when I try to call it into the fragment, the app crashes

Comment: GetUsage is ur ACtivity??

Comment: Yep, GetUsage is the activity

Comment: I'm thinking of calling this activity separately and make it store the data I need in a file or something and then calling the file because calling the file in a fragment seems to work okay

Answer (score 0):

Change the Line  **int callsMade = new GetUsage().getCallDetails();**  to the following code

```
 Activity activity = getActivity();
 if(activity instanceof GetUsage)
  {
  GetUsage myactivity = (GetUsage) activity;
  myactivity.getCallDetails();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me with this, I really appreciate it.

I tried what you suggested and the if statement doesn't run (I put a log message in their to try it). What is this line attempting to do or do you know why this is happening?

Comment: In which Activity you are inflating this fragment--Wats the praent Activity for your fragment??

Comment: My MainActivity. All it does on inflates the fragment and controls the tabs for the fragments